# var_dump returns NULL, print_r returns nothing

Tags: php, html

I'm not sure why, but var_dump on $_POST['q1'] keeps returning NULL and when I try to use print_r it returns nothing, can anyone explain to me why?

```
    <?php
        $fields = array('tester_name','tester_email','reviewer_email','q1','q2',
                'q3','q4','q5','q6','q7','q8','q9','q10');


        $errors = array();
        $x = 0;
            foreach($fields as $key => $field) {
                if (isset($_POST[$field])) {    
                    if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
                        $errors[$x] = $field;
                        ++$x;
                    }
                } else { exit; }
            }
        ?>


<form style="padding-left:25px;" method="POST" action="all.php">

    <p><b>1.</b> How many Zodiac Signs are there?<br />
            <input class="qIn" type="radio" name="q1" value="11" <?php if($_POST['q1']=="11") echo 'checked'; ?> />11<br />
            <input class="qIn" type="radio" name="q1" value="12" <?php if($_POST['q1']=="12") echo 'checked'; ?> />12<br />
            <input class="qIn" type="radio" name="q1" value="13" <?php if($_POST['q1']=="13") echo 'checked'; ?> />13<br />
            <input class="qIn" type="radio" name="q1" value="14" <?php if($_POST['q1']=="14") echo 'checked'; ?> />14<br /></p>

         <input style="margin-left:120px;" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: How do you submit `q1` field? Could you, please, add complete html-form markup?

Comment: What is in the starting tag of the form? Did you submit the form? Did you select a radio button?

Comment: added the form and submit button.

Comment: Try using `print_r($_POST)` so you can see all the data that is being posted. In another test, you could try `print_r($_REQUEST)`, as it will show up all data being sent either via `POST` or `GET` methods.

Comment: Do you end up at all.php?

Comment: Looks like `else { exit; }` kills script before it managed to do something.

Comment: Why you are using same name 'q1' for all input field ?

Comment: @rncrtr yes, the actual document is all.php so it runs on itself.

Comment: @mathielo I think you are onto something, when I used both neither returned the key or value for q1, what would this indicate when not even the key is returned?

Comment: @tripleddev By default, for `radio` and `checkbox` inputs, if no value is checked the field is never sent when the form is submitted. I did a little test with the code you provided and it worked just fine. So my best guess is: your problem is outside the code you posted. Take a step back and look again **all** the code from that page, you're probably setting some other `<input name="q1">` that is conflicting with this set of "zodiac" inputs.

Comment: @mathielo basically everytime I submitted the form the radio groups weren't selected and therefore weren't set, so I have a loop that displays a message next to each field that isn't set (i.e. the radio groups), anyways thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close a `{` . Here's your modified code and also comment the `exit` line of code.

```
<?php
$fields = array('tester_name','tester_email','reviewer_email','q1','q2',
    'q3','q4','q5','q6','q7','q8','q9','q10');


$errors = array();
$x = 0;
foreach($fields as $key => $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
        if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
            $errors[$x] = $field;
            ++$x;
        }
    } else {
    //echo "fails";
    //exit;// }
}
}
?>


<form style="padding-left:25px;" method="POST" action="all.php">

    <p><b>1.</b> How many Zodiac Signs are there?<br />
        <input class="qIn" type="radio" name="q1" value="11" <?php if($_POST['q1']=="11") echo 'checked'; ?> />11<br />
        <input class="qIn" type="radio" name="q1" value="12" <?php if($_POST['q1']=="12") echo 'checked'; ?> />12<br />
        <input class="qIn" type="radio" name="q1" value="13" <?php if($_POST['q1']=="13") echo 'checked'; ?> />13<br />
        <input class="qIn" type="radio" name="q1" value="14" <?php if($_POST['q1']=="14") echo 'checked'; ?> />14<br /></p>

    <input style="margin-left:120px;" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Which curly one is mismatched? I can't find one. That said, my guess would have been that `exit;` on its own is a syntax error, that it should have been `exit();` instead.