# Prevent php from turning false into empty value

Tags: php

When using json_decode, boolean values of false gets turned into empty values. The json string I am using has values that can be empty, false, 1 or some text value, and I only want to use the fields that have values, even if the value is false. So when doing

```
$array = array();
foreach($obj as $key => $value){
  if($value != ''){
    $array[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

fields with false values dont get saved into $array. Is there a way around that?

Update: When doing print_r($obj) all false values are empty. So I dont think the != is the problem. if I print_r the json string empty values are "null" and false values are "false", but when print_r-ing the json_decoded object both turn into empty values.

Comment: Topically Related: [Print_r doesn't return anything; var_dump shows NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34456929/2943403) and [var_dump returns NULL, print_r returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18809142/2943403) and [What's the difference between echo, print, and print_r in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1647322/2943403)

Answer (score 2):

Use `!==` instead of `!=` if you want to check for empty strings without considering other *empty* values.

- [Comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
- [Type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)
- [Type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score 2):

Your false disappear because of

```
if($value != ''){
```

use

```
if($value !== ''){
```

because false in php is empty and your validation != stops false from passing

Answer (score 1):

change comparison from `!=` to `!==`

```
$array = array();
foreach($obj as $key => $value){
  if($value !== ''){
    $array[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question ranks high in Google so it's worth sharing some facts to avoid confusion:

- Despite what the title may suggest, **`json_decode()` does not have the ability to turn `false` into empty string**, not even intentionally. If you've facing such case in your JSON-based application, the error must be somewhere else.
- [print_r()](https://php.net/print_r) is not a reliable tool to inspect boolean variables because it casts everything to string, and PHP casts boolean false as empty string. Use [var_dump()](https://php.net/var_dump) instead.

  ```
  $input = [true, false, ''];
  print_r($input);
  var_dump($input);
  ```

  ```
  Array
  (
      [0] => 1
      [1] => 
      [2] => 
  )
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    bool(true)
    [1]=>
    bool(false)
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ```
- PHP has two ≠ operators: loose (`!=`) and strict (`!==`). The former will apply type conversions to decide if values match, the latter will reject equality when types differ. You specifically want to avoid loose operator when you need to distinguish between null, false, empty string, number zero and string that starts with zero.

Comment: I would rather edit the title to make the question less confusing.

Comment: @YourCommonSense It's hard to say whether Google will lower the rank. Searching for problems that include keywords like "false", "null", "empty"... renders fairly random results. You have a point, though, I'll look into it.

Comment: Said that, I honestly can't fully understand what's being asked here or what a good title+description could be.